# Spinner getSelectedView() is null

Tags: android, android-spinner

I got a spinner it has 6 items in it, I can see them.when I call spinner.getSelectedView(), it is always null

Any idea why?

```
sortSpinner.setSelection(2);
CheckedTextView v = (CheckedTextView) sortSpinner.getSelectedView(); //crash null pointer
v.setChecked(true);
```

Edit:

I am extending ArrayAdapter for the spinner's adapter

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<String> objects;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context ctx, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> placeTypes) {
        super(ctx, layoutResourceId, placeTypes);
        this.context = ctx;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.objects =placeTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
    }

    class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView title;
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            //Utils.setFontRobotLight(context, viewHolder.title);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String str = objects.get(position);
        viewHolder.title.setText(str);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

.

```
 ArrayList<String> sortList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sortArr));
 CustomSpinnerAdapter sortAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner_adapter_view_red,
                    sortList);
 sortSpinner.setAdapter(sortAdapter);
```

Error from stack trace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{my.activity.name}: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.CheckedTextView.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object
>   reference

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckedTextView.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
my.package.name.setSort(MyActivity.java:555)
my.package.name.onCreate(MyActivity.java:413)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
```

Line 55 is v.setChecked(true)

Comment: Does `setSelection` work? Also is `sortSpinner` null or the result of `getSelectedView`

Comment: @ChrisStillwell setSelection works and sortSpinner is not nulll its the result  of getSelectedView that is null

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?  I'm confused by how the line `sortSpinner.setSelection(2)` would be okay but `sortSpinner.getSelectedView` would cause a null pointer exception.  Is it possible that `v.setChecked(true)` is where the crash occurs?

Comment: You are overriding `getView` but there is no `CheckedTextView` item in your viewHolder (at least nothing I can see...). What does your item's XML look like?

Comment: Sounds like the NPE is in your getCustomView method. LIkely with String str = objects.get(position). Of course, the stack trace tells you exactly where the error happened, so I'm confused as to your confusion.

Comment: @iheanyi I have updated the question with the stack trace, there is nothing helpful there

Comment: @ChrisStillwell its a simple CheckedTextView. TextView also gives the same error

Comment: @Michiyo I have updated the question with the stacktrace

Comment: Can you set an OnItemClickListener and call `getSelectedView()` from inside that? It seems that `setSelection()` requests a layout, which would create the views, but this will happen asynchronously and won't have happened when you call `getSelectedView()` immediately afterwards. Bit out on a limb here, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @ci_ that gave me the idea to put getSelectedView() inside spinner.post() and it worked. thanks